# Setting different initial zoom level for iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, viewport, meta

I have the following `<meta>` tag in my `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
```

This works fine, except that I want to use a slightly different default zoom level for iPad (and preferably all devices within a certain screen width range), something like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.9, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=0.9, user-scalable=1">
```

Is this possible without server-side useragent detection? Preferably using javascript. I tried to change it based on the `navigator.plattform` string, but the `initial-scale` doesn’t play nice if you change it after it’s already set.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answering this myself, but I found a way using `document.write`:

```
(function( zoom ){
    document.write('\x3Cmeta name="viewport" content="'+
                   'width=device-width,'+
                   'initial-scale='+zoom+','+
                   'maximum-scale=2,'+
                   'minimum-scale='+zoom+','+
                   'user-scalable=1">');
}( /ipad/i.test(navigator.platform)?'0.9':'1') )
```

Comment: There's gotta be a better way to do this.